# base64 encoded image (.png) to byte[] insert into xml (open xml sdk) - ' ', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character

Tags: c#, xml, image, asp.net-web-api, openxml

This is a tricky one. I have a base64 encoded image passed from a client side app, to a c# API server side.

Upon receiving Server-side, I convert the image to a byte[], whereby I try to insert it into my Powerpoint Presentation Slide making use of the Open Xml Sdk.

From my searches on SO and the net, what I could find so far is that it is a problem with XML that don't allow certain characters, in this case **0x0B (a vertical tab if I'm not mistaken)**.

Now, I don't really know my options at this point, but the only other thing I can think of, is to save the image to disk first, then include it in my powerpoint programitacally **but this is not ideal, as I want to do as little as possible directly on the disk, I don't even save the powerpoint on the disk, I email it directly from a Stream**.

I can't "sanitize" the image for illegal chars, cause that would break the image, the same way as removing even just one of the characters in the raw base64 encoded string breaks it.

Is there any other alternative? Maybe someone who has had the same issue with normal XML and a byte[] of an image that somehow got a workaround? I include my code for my method below. (The code breaks on the last line, **newSlidePart.Slide.Save();** with the following message:

**' ', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character.** or **"'\v', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character."**

Can anyone help please?

```
//assign imageID
            const int imageIdStartId = 1;

            string imgId = "ImgID" + imageIdStartId;

            //Add new image part to slide
            ImagePart imgPart = newSlidePart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, imgId);

            //Feed the data to the new imgPart
            imgPart.FeedData(new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes.ToArray()));

            //find blip
            Blip blip = newSlidePart.Slide.Descendants<Blip>().First();

            //IMPORTANT - property embed refers to ppt image, point this to correct image ID, i.e. one just created.
            blip.Embed = imgId;

            //Finally save the slide
            newSlidePart.Slide.Save();
```

Method for creating an image from my base64 string:

```
private byte[] CreateImageFromBase64String(string modelSceneImageContent)
    {
        try
        {


            string[] validImage = modelSceneImageContent.Split(',');
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(validImage[1]);

            #region if we want to save to an image
            //Image image;

            //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            //{
            //  image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            //  //FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"]), FileMode.Create);
            //  File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"]), bytes);
            //}
            #endregion

            //return raw bytes for image replac in ppt (see above for image save to bmp then returning image as alternative)
            return bytes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Exception(ex, "Error in powerpoint template retrieval.");

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm really open to any suggestions, different encoding schemes etc.

Comment: What is the part that throws an exception, in your code ?

Comment: @cosmo0, it is newSlidePart.Slide.Save();

Comment: Does it happen with every png image or just one ? Have you tried ClosedXML (a wrapper around the OpenXML lib) ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. It happens just with one image out of about 30+ images. And it started happening yesterday. Copying and pasting the base64 image into chrome works fine. IT displays the image just like the others which is strange. @cosmo0, I'll have a look into it. I am beginning to think, adding an alternative if the first method fails, then copy the images to disk and insert them into the pptx from disk and then do cleanup. So foreach image, do first method, if fails, do second. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Closed XML is just for excel :(

Comment: How do you convert the image to a `byte[]`? Using `FromBase64String` directly _should_ work. E.g. `imgPart.FeedData(new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(yourBase64String)));`

Comment: @petelids, please my update, second method above. I do string[] validImage = modelSceneImageContent.Split(',');
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(validImage[1]);

Comment: I don't think it'll help tbh, was more a style comment :(

Comment: yes, I get an error now. Error 168 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>' to 'int'. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Where does the value in modelSceneImageContent comes from ?

Comment: @cosmo0, it's the image string e.g. data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABkAAAAMgCAYAAAB7wK5aAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAP+6SURBVHhe7J0FXFRLF8DP9i7dLSAICKKi2Irdig12d3d/Kna32B2oYHcrdoCBooQgKCHdbO9+M3cvJaC etc etc etc etc passed to it.

Comment: Yes but how do you transform the original image to this string ?

Comment: Correct. We did this and passed it to the server.

Comment: *It happens just with one image out of about 30+ images.*  Are you sure that specific image is not corrupt?  Can you save it and load it into Internet Explorer?

Comment: @dbc, yes copying the string directly into chrome displays the image fine, no problems (first thing I checked :) ) .

Comment: I can even save the file to disk and open the image etc. No problems